# Как установить win 7 на ПК?

Tags: установка, windows-7

Извините за примитивный вопрос.
*(Рос на win95-х, 98-х, millenium-ах и XP-шках.)*
Поэтому не знаю, как устанавливать Win 7

Дано:

1. ПК без привода (дисков всё равно под рукой нет) с установленной (и упавшей) Win7 (?-bit)
2. есть загрузочный Флэш-накопитель с дистрибутивом win 7 64-bit (сама ОС на флэшке 32-бит)

Вопрос: как?
Примечание: тыкаю setup.exe - "Программа не запускается" (значит setup.exe уже 64-битный exe)
Предположение: Ни как... так как ни как не заведётся, что-то 64 битное в 32-битной среде.

Answer (score 1):

> есть загрузочный Флэш-накопитель с дистрибутивом win 7 64-bit (сама ОС на флэшке 32-бит)

это как?
Вообще, у MS есть утилита позволяющая создать загрузочную флэшку, если есть образ винды. Думаю, стоит воспользоваться ей.
[Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool#installation)

Comment: Это так.Флэш накопитель с ОС аля win 32 bit (воткнул, загрузился - для административных нужд). Разве это что-то новое? Флэш-накопитель с ОСью? Для технических нужд и прочего.Вот, а на нём, на флэш-накопителе, лежат всякие админские тулзы + ось в дистрибутиве и она 64-бит.  P.S. re: *"Вообще, у MS есть утилита позволяющая создать"*На MS я клал большой своп-файл, так как у самого ручки из плеч. растут.

Comment: to be continued:   И ещё: флэш-накопитель с нужнейшей информацией, так что предложение по форматированию и созданию чисто, лишь установочной флэш, меня не устраивает. 32-х битная же стартует из под ОСи с флэш.  Вот и вопрос: Имеется ли возможность с ОСи 32-bit (которая на flash? да хоть и не на flash) стартануть инсталляцию Win 7 64bit?

Comment: А если попробовать, загрузившись с флэшки, сделать загрузочным жесткий диск, на который надо установить ОС? Сам я такого не пробовал, но вдруг да сработает?  http://daascom.com/computer/consultation/USB-boot-make-sposob1.html  по ссылке руководство для создания загрузочной флэхи, но мож и с hdd сработает?

Comment: Ого! интересный вариант =)Но я плюнул и поставил 32 бита 7-ку.

Answer (score 0):

мотри, что есть в авторане на дистрибутиве 7-ки 64-бит:

open=sources\sperr32.exe x64icon=sources\sperr32.exe,0

а?т.е. попробуй запустить не "сэтап" из корня, а sperr32.exe x64, - может твой случай?там, кстати и "сэтап" какой-то есть. у него другой размер, чем у того, что снаружилады, покедова, удачи,у-да-чи!!!

Comment: Хороший вариант для исследования, я пробовал, но ключи как-то не догадался прописать. особенно "X64" интересен.  А про "снаружи" setup'ы, что они для юзеров, это мы проходили.

Comment: И кстати автора, это всего лишь для запуска win-приложений, но не как не загрузка с применением boot-секторов, в которых что-то похитрее прописано.